# Node classification with random labels for GNNs

Tags: classification, labeling, graph-neural-network

I decided to train GCN on the Cora dataset for the node classification task, however, with the random labels, i.e., applying `np.random.shuffle(labels)`. For the default set of parameters, I am getting an accuracy of around 0.3 for the test set and 0.4 for the train set. I expect that for the random labels, the accuracy would be `1/number of classes`. So in the case of Cora: `1/7 = 0.14`.

Do you have any intuition why graph neural networks perform better than the random case? I am aware that in [1] authors trained the models on the random labels and achieved perfect results on the train set. However, for test size they still were around the `1/number of classes`.

I checked simpler models such as RandomForests or SVC and the final accuracy for the test size is indeed 1/7.

[1] Zhang, C., Bengio, S., Hardt, M., Recht, B., & Vinyals, O. (2021). Understanding deep learning (still) requires rethinking generalization. Communications of the ACM, 64(3), 107-115.

Comment: How are you creating your holdout set? I have struggled with understanding how such a set can exist in a graph. If a holdout node is connected to the in-sample nodes, then it should be passing messages at training time (it would seem), but then you aren’t treating the holdout data as if they don’t exist during the training steps.

Comment: The problem was that the Cora dataset was unbalanced. Here is a response https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/40684/30292.